# Two computers cannot ping one another - both connected to the same switch

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, arp

I've got two physical computers which are connected to the same unmanaged switch. Said switch is connected to a server handing out IP addresses and acting as a gateway.

This works fine. Clients that plug into the network get an IP, and can access the internet. Those two computers can also access the internet and the gateway.

Here's the hard part. Those two computers cannot communicate with one another. More specifically, neither can get a mac address using ARP, the table lists the entry as INCOMPLETE. Manually setting an address yields no results.

The gateway machine, as well as any other computer on the network, can ping and communicate just fine.

Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: If it helps, VPN clients connected through one computer exhibit the same issues.

Comment: What happens if you tracert client 1 from client 2 ?

Comment: Are the firewalls up on the problematic machines?  if you trace between them, where does it get stuck?  If you just stick a wire between them and set static IP info, can they ping each-other then?

Comment: Destination Host Unreachable, same as a ping. ARP never resolves.

Comment: Firewalls are down, and other machines can ping/trace to both of them. Traceroutes don't even hop once, they just give "Destination Host Unreachable". Static IP also does not work.

Comment: Can you run a sniffer (e.g., Wireshark)? Running Wireshark on both machines, what do you see when you try to communicate between them?

Comment: Will do when I get back to the lab tomorrow.

Comment: @Scott, after running a sniffer(used tcpdump), I see requests for the computer's IP address, but never any responses. Pinging from the other computer shows nothing at all.

Comment: @science9712 What is the internal IP-address of both computers? And what is the subnet mask on the network?

Comment: 192.168.1.146 & 192.168.1.112, subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: @science9712 You say *Static IP* didn't work either. Did you try **different addresses**? Pick one outside the DHCP range but inside the mask range. 192.168.1.251 and 192.168.1.252 for instance. (maybe with ping a ping beforehand to be sure it's not already taken :)

Comment: @science9712 Ooo, and another remote possibility... did you happen to check if the MAC-addresses of the network adapters in those two computers are not the same.

Comment: Sadly, changing addresses didn't fix the problem. I did check the MAC addresses, good guess. I've also tried to do an arping to the mac address, didn't do anything.

Comment: @science9712 Those computer just don't *like* each other ;) Did you try flushing the ARP-table? See [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tips-flush-the-arp-cache-in-windows-7/). You can do `netsh interface ip delete arpcache` at a administrator prompt. (Also check if its empty after doing this with a `arp -a`) Do this on both computers.

Comment: Done on both. One's Linux, one's Windows, so I did the `ip n flush` to clear on linux, and that command on Windows. Didn't do anything. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @science9712 is it possible to swap the network adapter with one of the working computers and seeing if the problem moves with it?

Comment: Solved it finally! Turns out there was something odd with that switch. Changing it out fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by changing the switch out with a completely different brand and model.

Comment: Mmmhhh... I remember a similar issue a couple of years ago. Power fluctuation corrupted the CAM-table in the switch. Rebooting the switch solved the problem (reboot clears table). My colleagues had been trying to troubleshoot for several hours when they told me it started acting up around 8:15 in the morning. I remembered that I had seen the lights flicker briefly around that time. They never noticed because the lights in their office where on a different circuit. Flicker was too short to reboot anything, but bad enough to corrupt the CAM-table.

Comment: Yeah, using different ports on the switch was going to be my next suggestion. But... didn't you do what @techie007 suggested 2 days ago, connecting both computers directly to each other with a cable and setting a static ip and checking if they see each other?  That should have worked if it was a switch problem! (Second comment on your question)

Comment: I did. I'm confused by it, and chances are it's going to stop working a week from now, but for now I'm going to leave it and hope it works. The joys of non-production systems :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the switch has client isolation enabled.  This is especially common with wireless access points and switches.  The clients can talk to the switch and anything upstream from it, but are prevented from talking to each other as a security measure.

Comment: I would agree, however other clients plugged into the switch can ping and communicate with both those computers, and other clients.

Comment: Ah, right.  I missed that bit in your original post.  Can either of the misbehaving machines be pinged from other machines on the network?  Perhaps they're refusing ICMP packets?

Comment: They can be pinged from anywhere on the network. It's driving me crazy because the only connection that isn't working is between the two machines.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After reading this problem story, I checked the description of the switch and found it has a VLAN switch meant to seperate the clients of the switch. It was set ON, but should be OFF to allow trafic between the clients. That solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).